# IEnumerable Any or Count throws Exception

Tags: c#-4.0

```
IEnumerable<ColorRow> result = (from a in Fruit.Apple.Colors where (a.color == "red") select a);
```

If i try using result.Any() or Count() it throws exception when no result is returned, I understand above ColorRow would be null, but how do i check this?

will changing the above to var result help is it equivalent to Colrow result = new ColorRow ??

Not sure how to handler IEnumerable above for nulls,empty.

I am currently using a try and catch but doesn't seem clean.

```
try
{
result.FirstOrDefault().Color= "pink";
return true;
}
catch
{
return false;
}
```

Comment: `null` != empty! Please show the actual code that throws an exception and tell us what exception it is - and what its error message is.

Comment: @ Daniel : Result.FirstOrDefault() throws NullreferenceException: Object reference not set to the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am currently using a try and catch but doesn't seem clean.

Instead of try catch, you can check the object against null and then compare the color.

```
var temp = result.FirstOrDefault();
if(temp != null && temp.Color == "Pink")
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

For the other question regarding `Any` and `Count` are you sure that your code is compiling, because you seems to be querying `Fruit.Apple.Colors` and you are create IEnumerable of `ColorRow`, It should be:

```
IEnumerable<Color>....
```

*(If using implicitly type (var) is fixing the issue the probably you are using the wrong type in assignment)*

Comment: Result.FirstOrDefault() throws NullreferenceException: Object reference not set to the instance. Just assume that ColorRow could be initialized if any row is matched or else not, how do i find instead of catch the exception that object is null?